# How to set a hyperlink to table position?

Tags: html, html-table

How can I set a hyperlink to table position? Like this:

```
<a href="#pos1">Click to scroll</a>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr name="pos1">
    ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an ID to the tr.

```
<a href="#pos1">Click to scroll</a>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="pos1">
    ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an ID to the table row `<tr name="pos1" id="pos1">`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bs7m4w1s/)**

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#anchors-with-id

Answer (score 0):

Add a named anchor within the row:

```
<a href="#pos1">Click to scroll</a>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a name="pos1"></a>...</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's an invalid location for this tag, isn't it?

Comment: I meant within the first element in that row.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` element to the `<tr>` like this:

```
<a href="#pos1">Click to scroll</a>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="pos1" name="pos1">
    ...
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When the anchor will be clicked, it will take the browser screen to the referred ID of the element.

Means if an anchor has `href` attribute to pos1 like `href="#pos1"`, it will search for the element with that is and take the screen to that element!